# Writing unit tests for Python API rate limiter (TDD approach)

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

I'm trying to teach myself TDD as I've never learned it and am using a practice problem. The prompt was to create an API rate limiter that returns true or false once a given customerID has hit a specified number of API requests. The code I wrote up in Python was:

```
import time
from time import sleep


class PreciseRateLimiter(object):
   def __init__(self, max_requests, time_interval_ms):
     # initialize max requests allowed
     self._max_requests = max_requests
     # initialize time frequency
     self._time_interval_ms = time_interval_ms
     # initialize hash table
     self._clientIDs = {}

  def is_allowed(self, clientID):
    # capture current timestamp in milliseconds to make it as exact as possible. Seconds would be rounded.
    current_ms_time = round(time.time() * 1000)

    # check if there is anything in the hash table
    if clientID in self._clientIDs:
        # check if the incoming request is greater than the maximum requests allowed (if 100 requests max, this would be 101)
        if len(self._clientIDs[clientID]) >= self._max_requests:
            time_diff = current_ms_time - self._clientIDs[clientID][-1]
            self._clientIDs[clientID].pop()
            self._clientIDs[clientID].append(current_ms_time)
            if time_diff < self._time_interval_ms:
                return False
        # if the income request is not greater (meaning its 100 or less), append to the list
        else:
            self._clientIDs[clientID].append(current_ms_time)
    # if there is nothing in the hash table, create a list for that clientId and append
    else:
        self._clientIDs[clientID] = list()
        self._clientIDs[clientID].append(current_ms_time)
    return True

myLimiter = PreciseRateLimiter(100, 1000)
max_counter = 101
counter = 1
while counter <= max_counter:
    sleep(0.01)
    print('counter: {} result: {}'.format(counter, myLimiter.is_allowed(1)))
    counter += 1
```

How would I go about writing test cases for this particular problem using TDD? So far what I understand is I will create a fail test, test it to make sure it fails, change the code so the test will pass, and once it passes refactor the code. I guess I'm having trouble figuring out how to know what exactly to test.

Comment: You can't write tests using TDD, because you've written the code. And what exactly to test is: does it do what it's supposed to? In this case, given some traffic, does it say yes and no at the appropriate times?

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I was asking more in the sense of if I was in the process of writing this code and didn't know it worked yet, how would I test? So before writing any code, I could start with a general test such as calling the is_allowed() method before it's created to make it fail, create the method and get the is_allowed() method to print 'hello' so that it passes, and then continue modifying the test and checking if pieces of code work as I go? Sorry if this is a silly question lol

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I'm having trouble figuring out how to know what exactly to test.

"Behavior" is what to test; which is to say "what information comes out of the object when you feed it these inputs".  Information can take the form of an answer to a question, or information that gets sent "somewhere else".

When performing TDD, the usual sequence is to start from a "simple" behavior, and after you have a clean design that passes that test, you start introducing additional complexity until you have covered the entire behavior space.

(Sometimes, when we can't get the traction we want to describe a simple behavior, we take a time out to perform a "spike", and write some throw away code -- like what you have here -- to get a better sense for what's supposed to be happening).

If we look at your spike, we might see a couple important (but simple) ideas to start from:

- a new clientID is always allowed.
- if max_retries is "infinite", then any finite number of visits will be allowed
- if max_retries is 1, and time_interval_ms is infinite, then a client is allowed exactly once

The challenging bits all come about when max_retries and time_interval_ms are "small", so we save that test until we have the east checks taken care of.

If you've been burned by "time" often enough, you'll recognize that complicated logic tightly coupled to a clock is a "code smell", and so your design might change a little bit in response

```
  def is_allowed(self, clientID):
    # capture current timestamp in milliseconds to make it as exact as possible. Seconds would be rounded.
    current_ms_time = round(time.time() * 1000)
    return self.is_allowed_at(clientID, current_ms_time)

  def is_allowed_at(self, clientID, current_ms_time):
    # check if there is anything in the hash table
    ...
```

... and then aim your tests at is_allowed_at, using the extra control to evaluate your behaviors in [edge cases that are difficult to produce organically](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time).

---

> I guess I was asking more in the sense of if I was in the process of writing this code and didn't know it worked yet, how would I test?

One behavior at a time.  The very first test has a lot of friction (you are going from nothing to something), so I recommend choosing a test that will be easy to type.  Hack in the right answer to make the test pass, then clean up the code so that the test is passing for the right reason.

At that point, you get another guess at which test will be the easiest to pass next.  And having guessed another test, you decide whether you want to add that test immediately, or first do more cleanup on the implementation to make passing this next test easy ("Make the next change easy, then make the easy change).  You know that you've made a good choice if the wall clock time required to make the new failing test pass is really short.